# How to fix a progress bar at the terminal's last line using python?

Tags: python, terminal, tqdm

For a large scan over a parameter space for a scientific calculation which takes several hours on my computer, I want to implement a progress bar (like from the `tqdm` package). During the computations of the program I want the program to print where exactly it is on the grid over which it searches and some error messages using `print()`. Using the standard code from `tqdm` resulted in a bar in every some lines of code but not in a progress bar in the last line of the terminal as would be good for my application.

Here is a minimal version of what I mean:

```
from tqdm import tqdm
from time import sleep

for i in tqdm(range(10), position=0, leave=True):
    print("\nAfter this comment there will be a new progress bar.")
    sleep(0.5)
```

The code snippet yields an output like:

```
  0%|                                                    | 0/10 [00:00<?, ?it/s]
After this comment there will be a new progress bar.
 10%|████▍                                       | 1/10 [00:00<00:04,  2.00it/s]
After this comment there will be a new progress bar.
 20%|████████▊                                   | 2/10 [00:01<00:04,  2.00it/s]
After this comment there will be a new progress bar.
 30%|█████████████▏                              | 3/10 [00:01<00:03,  2.00it/s]
After this comment there will be a new progress bar.
 40%|█████████████████▌                          | 4/10 [00:02<00:03,  1.99it/s]
After this comment there will be a new progress bar.
 50%|██████████████████████                      | 5/10 [00:02<00:02,  1.99it/s]
After this comment there will be a new progress bar.
 60%|██████████████████████████▍                 | 6/10 [00:03<00:02,  1.99it/s]
After this comment there will be a new progress bar.
 70%|██████████████████████████████▊             | 7/10 [00:03<00:01,  1.99it/s]
After this comment there will be a new progress bar.
 80%|███████████████████████████████████▏        | 8/10 [00:04<00:01,  1.99it/s]
After this comment there will be a new progress bar.
 90%|███████████████████████████████████████▌    | 9/10 [00:04<00:00,  1.99it/s]
After this comment there will be a new progress bar.
100%|███████████████████████████████████████████| 10/10 [00:05<00:00,  1.99it/s]
```

Do you know of an alternative for tqdm, a quick implementation of a progress bar that remains below and just grows (together with the functionality that tqdm delivers) or maybe the right arguments I would just have to give tqdm?

Thank you!

Comment: I have used tqdm, most of the times it works odd version >3.5 https://python.libhunt.com/tqdm-alternatives. Check this link for alternates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you're looking for the [.write()](https://github.com/tqdm/tqdm#writing-messages) method of tqdm.

That said, my solution here would be to log to a file if you really need text output and the progress bar.

Notice that with the defaults you know which iteration the error / output was printed without having to provide that in via a variable/exc_info or similar. I very rarely use tqdm.write() for this reason.

Answer (score 1):

You could use [Rich](https://github.com/willmcgugan/rich) which allow you to print while displaying a progress bar.

Comment: Thank you! Definitely superior to `tqdm`! It's as easy as adding `from rich.progress import track` and using `track()` instead of `tqdm()`. So convenient!